# Using swig, how do I pass binary data from python to C/C++?

Tags: python, c, swig

If I have a C or C++ function like this in my my_module.h:

```
void my_function(const char* data, int len);
```

And my_module.c:

```
#include "my_module.h"

#include <unistd.h>

void my_function(const char* data, int len)
{
    // do fancy things with data
    write(1, data, len);
}
```

I will create a my_module.i for swig like this:

```
%inline %{
#include "my_module.h"
%}
%include "my_module.h"
```

I build like this:

```
swig -python -module my_module my_module.i

gcc -shared -fPIC my_module_wrap.c my_module.c -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lpython3.8 -o _my_module.so
```

Now from python I want to do this:

```
import my_module

in_file = open("my_binary_file", "rb")
bytes = in_file.read()
in_file.close()

my_module.my_function(bytes, len(bytes))
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: in method 'find_mistakes', argument 1 of type 'char const *'
```

I inspected type of the variable `bytes`

```
>>> type(bytes)
<class 'bytes'>
```

I don't know what that means. How do I just get the raw data to pass to C?

I don't want to convert the bytes to string, because it is not text. And when I tried to have convert it anyway the C side received text that encodes the binary instead of the raw binary. Something that looks like this:

```
b'\x\x00\n'
```

Edit:

Reading the [manual](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn10) I found this:

> The char * datatype is handled as a NULL-terminated ASCII string. SWIG maps this into a 8-bit character string in the target scripting language. SWIG converts character strings in the target language to NULL terminated strings before passing them into C/C++. The default handling of these strings does not allow them to have embedded NULL bytes. Therefore, the char * datatype is not generally suitable for passing binary data. However, it is possible to change this behavior by defining a SWIG typemap. See the chapter on Typemaps for details about this.

So swig says `char*` is good for text, but not for binary data. What is the alternative to `char*` that works then?

It suggests changing swig's default behavior using typemaps. Is this the only way? If so, how is it done? And will it be a different hack for each language?

Comment: Have you tried these kind of declarations, `char *const c;` or `const char *const d`? Source: http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn13

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's the same issue: `TypeError: in method 'my_function', argument 1 of type 'char const *const'`

Comment: Ohhh, have you tried `const char *const`? I think you misread the second declaration style. (Still not sure if this will fix your problem though)

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried, the error says 'char const *const' but it's the same exact type anyway

Comment: Ok2. Thanks for the confirmation. I don't have any more ideas as of the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of frustration, I finally did it. Hopefully this answer saves other people some time and frustration.

Note that this answer works for python 3. I don't know how things would work with python 2.

From the [docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn77):

> In some cases, users may wish to instead handle all byte strings as
> bytes objects in Python 3. This can be accomplished by adding
> SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR to the generated code:

This means you just need this in your interface file:

```
%begin %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
%}
```

> This will modify the behavior so that only Python 3 bytes objects will
> be accepted and converted to a C/C++ string, and any string returned
> from C/C++ will be converted to a bytes object in Python.

Bonus:

If you don't want to pass both the binary and the length from python you can do this in the interface file:

```
%include "typemaps.i"

// change "(const char* data, int len)" to match your functions declaration
%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (const char* data, int len) }

%include "my_module.h"
```

Now from python you can do this:

`my_module.my_function(bytes)` instead of `my_module.my_function(bytes, len(bytes))`

So my final interface file looks like this:

```
%module my_module

%begin %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
%}

%inline %{
#include "my_module.h"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"

%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (const char* data, int len) }

%include "my_module.h"
```